# search listbox in WP8 by a textbox input

Tags: c#, xaml, search, windows-phone-8, listbox

my  requirement :-
  searching  in  txtsearch letter  by  letter  and  showing  the   matched  letters  of  ITMNAME( textblock  inside  listbox)    and  highlight  that  particular  string..

my  xaml...

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1" >
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Height="150" Width="500" >
            <Grid Width="500" Height="150" Background="White" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.9*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Name="imgitem"  Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source="{Binding ImgSource}" Margin="0,5,4,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtbindprice"  Text="{Binding _PRICE,ConverterCulture=en-IN,StringFormat=C}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.Column="1"  Width="350"  Foreground="Black" Height="60" Margin="40,70,20,-10"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtFinalTotal"  Text="{Binding _FinalTotal}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.Column="1"  Width="350"  Foreground="Red" Height="60" Margin="40,115,20,-10"/>


                <TextBlock x:Name="txtITMNAME"  Text="{Binding _ITMNAME }" Padding="1"  Tap="ItmName_Tapped" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"  FontWeight="Normal" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  Foreground="OrangeRed" Width="Auto"  Height="150"  Margin="30,25,10,-10"/>

                <c4f:RoundButton    Grid.Column="2" Name="btntick" Click="btntick_Click" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="LightGray" Foreground="DarkGray" Margin="10,20,45,10"   />

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

<ListBox Height="Auto" Name="lstbxmanual" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1 }"  Width="475" Margin="2,192,0,-39" Background="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    </ListBox>


  <TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="CadetBlue" KeyUp="txtSearch_KeyUp" GotFocus="txtsearch_gotFocus" LostFocus="txtsearch_lostFocus"  FontSize="24" Background="White" Height="85" TextAlignment="Left"  Margin="1,-30,-2,30"   />
```

my  viewmodel

```
  #region "Bind"
    public class BindData
{
    public BitmapImage ImgSource { get; set; }
    public string _ITMNAME { get; set; }
    public string _PRICE { get; set; }
    public string _FinalTotal { set; get; }
}
    #endregion
```

my  binding

```
foreach ()
 {
     lstbxmanual.Items.Add(new BindData() { ImgSource = base64image(h[2]), _ITMNAME = h[3], _PRICE =string.Concat(ClsCommon.str_CurrencySymbol,h[1]), _FinalTotal = "" });

 }
```

by  this  I am  binding  entire  iterations  data  to  listbox(lstbxmanual)..

```
textbox  event  I  have  included

  private void txtSerach_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

       //  the  followig  throws  an  error  at  li.Equals  

        //var selectedItems = from li in lstbxmanual.Items
        //                    where li.Equals == txtSearch.Text
        //                    select li.Text;
       //  the  following  searches  only  by index  of  lstbox

       // if (lstbxmanual.Items.Contains(txtSearch.Text))
       //{

       //}
         }
```

[check  this](https://sharpsnippets.wordpress.com/2014/03/02/cxaml-listbox-search-filter-and-highlight-23/)

in the  above  link..they  binded all data   to  list  and   and then  searching..i am  not  using  any  kind  of list ..so  i  cant  implement it..

please help  regarding  this...
for  any  queries  revert  back..

Comment: `li._ITMNAME == txtSearch.Text` or `li._ITMNAME.Equals(txtSearch.Text)` ??

Comment: nope..not  working...

Comment: Your Listbox Itemsource is empty. so The Listbox unable to Locate the Items. Bind the ListboxItemSource. or Create a Observable collection and set that as a source of the Listbox

Comment: itemsource is  included..  i  havn't  included in this  question  as  it includes  large  quantity  of  code..